# CSS span not wrapping fully

Tags: html, css

I am having some issues with wrapping stuff to a new line when it reaches the max width. I have my blog set up displaying all of the tags in a single div, and when the first line reaches the max width the next tag should jump to the next line. (Attached is what is happening in Chrome and Firefox)

http://jsfiddle.net/QHWNF/7/

Here is the CSS Code:

```
p.tagHolder{
margin-bottom:5px;
line-height:25px;}
```

All the HTML/PHP is:

```
<a href="#"><span>TagName</span></a><a href="#"><span>TagName2</span></a>....
```

[image: Chrome]
[image: Firefox]

Comment: Maybe you could create a minimal fiddle (jsfiddle.net) that shows the problem. There you can even include your image.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try setting your spans to `display: inline-block`.

http://jsfiddle.net/QHWNF/10/

Comment: @Krewe - great this worked, that's what I was thinking -- that said, I would wrap the `<span>` around the `<a>` rather than the other way around, giving `<span class="tag"><a href="#">Test</a></span>` - saying, from my point of view: Here's a Thing that is a Tag, and this Tag links to (something).

Comment: The reason I put the `<a>` tag around the `<span>` tag because I want the user to be able to hover over the text to click AND the full grey box. Only reason why.

Answer (score 1):

Add `word-wrap: normal;` and `word-break: normal;` to your `span` and `p` container. This would make sure that words are broken only at allowed break-points when there's need for wrap.

I hope that helped!